# How to switch values between two sets?

Tags: r

Let's assume we have 2 sets, one with 3 particles and the other one is initially empty. Every 5 seconds a random particle switches between sets. The reaction should end when all 3 particles are in set B, and of course, when setA is empty.
The script I created is the following:

```
setA<-c(1,2,3)
setB<-c()
sets<-c(setA,setB)      
time<-0
while(length(setA) >= 0 && length(setB) < 3){
  particle<-sample(sets, 1)
  if (particle %in% setA){
    setA<-setA[-particle]
    setB<-c(setB, particle)}
  else {
    setB<-setB[-particle]
    setA<-c(setA, particle)}
  time <- time + 5
}
```

The loop has a lot of issues, firstly i get duplicate values, which should not exist, and most of the times the loop ends even if setA has still values in it.

Comment: "*Every 5 seconds a random particle switches between sets*". From `setA` to `setB` or is the other way round possible as well? And if so, is there any induced dependence? Another question. Assume only `1` is left in `setA`. Does it necessarily switch to `setB` or is it possible that one of two vacant positions in `setA` switch to `setb`?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are using `setA[-particle]`, but if `setA` only has the values `1, 3` in it, then it will be length 2. That means that if `particle` is 3, then you will have `setA[-3]`, but A doesn't have a 3rd element, so 3 is not removed from `setA`, despite being added to `setB`.

I think you are looking for `setdiff`:

```r
setA <- c(1,2,3)
setB <- c()
sets <- c(setA,setB)      
time <- 0

while(length(setA) >= 0 && length(setB) < 3){

  particle <- sample(sets, 1)
  if (particle %in% setA){
    setA <- setdiff(setA, particle)
    setB <- c(setB, particle)}
  else {
    setB <- setdiff(setB, particle)
    setA <- c(setA, particle)}

  time <- time + 5
}
```

This results in:

```r
setA
#> numeric(0)

setB
#> [1] 2 3 1
```

If you like, you can add in a `cat` statement to see what is happening at each step:

```r
setA <- c(1,2,3)
setB <- c()
sets <- c(setA,setB)      
time <- 0

while(length(setA) >= 0 && length(setB) < 3){
  cat('setA: ', setA, '      setB:', setB, '\n')
  particle <- sample(sets, 1)
  if (particle %in% setA){
    setA <- setdiff(setA, particle)
    setB <- c(setB, particle)}
  else {
    setB <- setdiff(setB, particle)
    setA <- c(setA, particle)}

  time <- time + 5
}
#> setA:  1 2 3       setB: 
#> setA:  2 3       setB: 1 
#> setA:  2       setB: 1 3 
#> setA:  2 3       setB: 1 
#> setA:  3       setB: 1 2 
#> setA:  3 1       setB: 2 
#> setA:  1       setB: 2 3 
#> setA:  1 3       setB: 2 
#> setA:  1       setB: 2 3
#> setA:        setB: 2 3 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Up front: you use the values ("particles") both as values and as indexes; the latter is wrong.

The problem would be clearer if you didn't use integer "particles" in your sets: for instance, if you use `setA <- c("A", "B", "C")`, then later in your code you would try (e.g.) `setA[-particle]` which could be `setA[-"A"]`, which does not work (it errs with `invalid argument to unary operator`). It would be better in this case to use `setdiff` or `! .. %in% ..` or some other mechanism.

I suggest shifting to letters at least to prove the point, then when comfortable you can shift back to integers.

```r
setA <- c("A", "B", "C")
setB <- c()
sets <- c(setA, setB)
time <- 0
iter <- 0
while (time < 10000 && length(setA) >= 0 && length(setB) < 3) {
  particle <- sample(sets, 1)
  fromA <- intersect(particle, setA)
  fromB <- intersect(particle, setB)
  if (length(fromA)) {
    setA <- setA[!setA %in% fromA]
    setB <- unique(c(setB, fromA))
  }
  if (length(fromB)) {
    setB <- setB[!setB %in% fromB]
    setA <- unique(c(setA, fromB))
  }
  time <- time + 5
}
```

Side note: I also added a condition `time < 10000`, an arbitrary number for sure. The point is to put in an active defense against an infinite loop. It's less needed when the code is correct, but if there's a mistake in your code (such that your other `while` conditions are always true) then it could misbehave.

I also changed the logic a little to allow for more than one particle, in case you're interested in changing the hard-coded `1` to a random number itself. This way, 2+ particles from one set or 1+ from each set can migrate. (Just in case you're interested in this.)